# How to set h264_qsv encoder based on ffmpeg4.3.1

Tags: ffmpeg

I upgrade ffmpeg from 4.1 to 4.3.1 in my project, and i found that video quality get very low(1920x1080 25fps 2048000).
How to config encoder parameters? Thanks a lot.

```
AVCodecContext* OpenH264Codec_QSV(int width, int height, int frameRate, int bitRate)
{
    AVCodec* c = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("h264_qsv");
    AVCodecContext* ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(c);
    ctx->width = width;
    ctx->height = height;
    ctx->bit_rate = bitRate;
    ctx->time_base.num = 1;
    ctx->time_base.den = frameRate;
    ctx->gop_size = frameRate;
    ctx->bit_rate_tolerance = ctx->bit_rate;
    ctx->rc_max_rate = ctx->bit_rate * 2.0;
    ctx->rc_min_rate = ctx->bit_rate * 0.1;
    //ctx->max_b_frames = 0;
    ctx->max_b_frames = 4;
    ctx->pix_fmt = c->pix_fmts[0];
    av_opt_set(ctx->priv_data, "preset", "medium", 0);
    av_opt_set(ctx->priv_data, "profile", "main", 0);
    av_opt_set(ctx->priv_data, "look_ahead", "0", 0);
    if (avcodec_open2(ctx, c, nullptr) < 0)
    {
        avcodec_free_context(&ctx);
        return nullptr;
    }
    return ctx;
}
```